# NReco(Generate PDF) not working on Godady server

Tags: pdf, nreco

I am using NReco for generating PDF it's working fine on local server but when i publish it on live server(GoDady)getting error

Cannot generate PDF: This program is blocked by group policy. For more information, contact your system administrator

Answer (score 1):

NReco PdfGenerator is a .NET wrapper for wkhtmltopdf tool; internally it is executed in separate process with System.Diagnostics.Process. Most shared ASP.NET hostings don't allow to execute external processed by ASP.NET applications; this means that you cannot use this component with restricted hosting environments like GoDaddy - this is mentioned in "Technical limitations" FAQ section on the component page.